# Android application crashes if JSON is empty

Tags: android, json, listview

I am developing an Application of JSON object Which Returns data into ListView.
if json have data then show data in listview..if dont have date then application is crashes.my application is crashes when json is empty.how to resolve this problem..thanx in advancce

here is android code..

```
public class EmployeePaymentHistory extends Fragment {
    HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ListView CategoryListView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    List<String> IdList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String TAG = EmployeePaymentHistory.class.getSimpleName();
    // Http Url For Filter Student Data from Id Sent from previous activity.


    String finalResult ;
    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    String ParseResult ;
    HashMap<String,String> ResultHash = new HashMap<>();
    String FinalJSonObject ;

    String TempItem;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_employee_payment, container, false);




        CategoryListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        //Receiving the ListView Clicked item value send by previous activity.
        TempItem =  getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("ListViewValue1");


        //Calling method to filter Student Record and open selected record.
        HttpWebCall(TempItem);



        // Add Click listener on Delete button.

        return  view;
    }

    // Method to Delete Student Record



    //Method to show current record Current Selected Record
    public void HttpWebCall(final String PreviousListViewClickedItem){

        class HttpWebCallFunction extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Loading Data",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                pDialog.dismiss();

                //Storing Complete JSon Object into String Variable.
                FinalJSonObject = httpResponseMsg ;

                //Parsing the Stored JSOn String to GetHttpResponse Method.
                new EmployeePaymentHistory.GetHttpResponse(getActivity()).execute();


            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                ResultHash.put("CustomerID",params[0]);

                ParseResult = httpParse.postRequest(ResultHash, api.EmployeePayment);

                return ParseResult;
            }
        }

        HttpWebCallFunction httpWebCallFunction = new HttpWebCallFunction();

        httpWebCallFunction.execute(PreviousListViewClickedItem);
    }


    // Parsing Complete JSON Object.
    private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public Context context;


        List<Customer> CategoryList;

        public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            try
            {
                if(FinalJSonObject != null)
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonObject);
                        JSONObject jsonObject;
                        Customer category;
                        CategoryList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            category = new Customer();

                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            category.CustomerName = jsonObject.getString("date").toString();
                            category.Customertotal = jsonObject.getString("account").toString();
                            category.CustomerPaid = jsonObject.getString("total").toString();
                            category.CustomerUnPaid = jsonObject.getString("status").toString();

                            CategoryList.add(category);

                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

 else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "abcc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            CategoryListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            CustomerListAdapterClass adapter = new CustomerListAdapterClass(CategoryList, context);

            CategoryListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }


}
```

here is php Api code:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

 $CustomerID= $_POST['CustomerID'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);

if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "sELECT b.payerid,a.account as account,b.date as date,b.status as status,b.type as type,sum(b.amount) as total FROM crm_employees a left JOIN sys_transactions b ON a.id = b.payerid where payerid= '$CustomerID' group by b.date ORDER BY a.id desc" ;



$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);

 }

} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}

 echo $json;

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: it will not crash if JSON empty or null, set condition where you setting the json values in views.

Comment: and show logcat

Comment: how to set condition..please send code

Comment: write the line in try catch where you are getting error or validate a case using if

Comment: @MunawarAkram i guess the problem is in your adapter. please show logcat and adapter code.

Comment: condition will be like: if(classObj.getCustomerName!=null)

Comment: Try replace: 'List<Customer> CategoryList;' with 'List<Customer> CategoryList = new ArrayList<Customer>();' Hope that helps!

Comment: thanx...working fine @I_A_Mok

Answer (score -1):

You need to give the response output same as you are parsing in android side. If you are trying to find a Json object of key name which is not in response then it will crash.

In this scenario you need to handle manually, the values you think it will be null or empty then handle using normal if statements.

Suppose `jsonObject.getString("date")` object is not fount then using if statements you can handle.

```
if(jsonObject.getString("date") != null){
  //code here
}
```